# Nagios Availability

Tags: report, nagios

It is possible to generate a Availability Report order by Time Ok? 
I'm trying to make in the nagios and centreon without any result.

Can someone tell me if it is possible and how to make it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking for is commonly called an SLA Report -- IE, a listing of services/hosts showing the amount of time in an OK (or scheduled downtime) state.

If you use the `Thruk` frontend for Nagios (required the livestatus plugin to be installed) then this has such a report built in.